# 400 Error while Uploading files to OneDrive with BITS-Protocol

Tags: c#, onedrive

I try to upload a file to OneDrive via BITS ([OneDrive Large File Upload API](https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85)).

I can create a session, but then when I want to upload the first Fragment, I receive an WebException with a 400 HTTP-Error (Bad request) while reading the response.
There are no further information in the exception.
My Code is like this:

```
string requestString = String.Format("https://cid-{0}.users.storage.live.com/items/{1}/{2}", userId, folderId, fileName);

WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestString);
webRequest.Headers.Add("X-Http-Method-Override", "BITS_POST");
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
webRequest.Headers.Add("BITS-Packet-Type", "Fragment");
webRequest.Headers.Add("BITS-Session-Id", sessionId);

webRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Range", String.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", contentOffset, (contentFragment.Count() + contentOffset), totalContentLength));

webRequest.ContentLength = contentFragment.Count();

webRequest.Method = "POST";


webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(contentFragment.ToArray(), 0, contentFragment.Count());

WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as WebResponse;
```

Here is a screenshot, to see the values for the first request, that is already failing:

[image]

Comment: The link you provided Needs authorization...

Comment: The link to GitHub? It is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've seen enough questions surrounding how to implement [this process](https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85) that I've created a quick little application that shows how it works. Take a look at the following gist, and see how it compares with what you're actually doing:

https://gist.github.com/ificator/3460d7b9d0bff74eb0ff

Comment: I'll give you a hint - the Content-Range header consists of inclusive offsets and a total length. When you say "0-4194304/1464449024" you're saying you're uploading from byte 0 to byte 4194304 for a total of 4194305 bytes. In your case you want subtract one from your end offset calculation.

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much. Such a stupid mistake, it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

The comments in the github project give a strong hint that a 400 response is associated with getting the Context-Range and ContentLength header values wrong.

That requires psychic debugging from the posted information, it is very inconsistent.  You report the fragment size as `contentLength` but actually upload a fragment that is `content.Count()` long.  A good opportunity for a mismatch and thus the 400 error.

So first suggestion I'd could come up with, assuming that `content` contains all of the uploadable data, is to use:

```
webRequest.GetRequestStream().
   Write(content.ToArray(), contentOffset, contentLength);
```

And the second, assuming that `content` only contains the fragment:

```
var length = content.Count();
webRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Range", String.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}",
    contentOffset, contentOffset + length - 1, totalContentLength));
webRequest.ContentLength = length;
```

Which incorporates the range fix as suggested by Brad and documented in [RFC-2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), section 14.16

Update your question to show more context if that did not help.

Comment: You are right, the example is not clear. I had to rewrite it to one function, to show all the code. I've updated my post, so that now it is clear, that it is a fragment of the content. There is also a screenshot where you can see the actual values

Comment: Well, you made it worse by now showing a variable named "offset", no hint how it is associated with "contentOffset" :)  One more detail I see now, the URL does not contain the trailing "HTTP/1.1" as shown in every example.

Comment: This answer makes the same mistake as the original question - the range header is suggesting that one more byte is being uploaded then is expected (since Content-Range deals with inclusive byte offsets). The value for {1} should be "contentOffset + length - 1".